# highcharts with JSON data -

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, highcharts

i've used highcharts before but went the C# route but decided to get my front end up to scratch and use Highcharts via front end:

I'm struggling to get the json data, well mainly get highcharts register the float data from my ajax call, here is the call/code

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.origin + "/WalletValue/GetAllValues",
            type: "GET",
            dataType:"json",

        }).done(function(data) {
           var value = data.map(x => parseFloat(x.Value).toFixed(2));
            Highcharts.chart('container',
                {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Wallet Value since 22 December 2017'
                    },

                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
                    },

                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Value'
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'middle'
                    },
                    series: [
                        {
                            name: 'Installation',
                            data: processed_json
                        }
                    ],
                });


        });
    });
</script>
```

it calls a API class that returns a list of this class:

```
   public class WalletValue
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You have `var value` but you are trying to pass `processed_json` to `series`.